# Need help in Optimizing my Gulp Task for SCSS compilation

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, node-modules

I configured this Gulp task for my local project. It is perfectly watching my folders, compiling the SCSS files to CSS.
Only problem is that -

> On an average my Gulp Task runs 'sass' task around 6 times in a second, whether I make any change in code or not. It keeps on running like this redundantly even after closing the IDE (SublimeText). I feel like it might not be a good practice and also compromising my machine's performance.

[image: screenshot of terminal]

**Here's my Gulp code:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
   return gulp.src('compile/style.scss')
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded',sourceComments: false}))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../../../compile'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('compile/**/*', gulp.series('sass'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass','watch'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a loop because of these two lines:

```
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../../../compile'))    // saving to compile


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('compile/**/*', gulp.series('sass'));  // watching compile
});
```

So your sass task runs , writes to the `compile` folder which the `watch` sees has changed and it fires the `sass` task again, over and over.

Save your sourcemaps somewhere that isn't including in your `watch` folders.

---

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
   return gulp.src('compile/style.scss')
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      .pipe(sass())                           // delete this, no need for two sass pipes
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded',sourceComments: false}))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../../../compile'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
});
```

Comment: oh.. I see. That does make sense. let me try this.

Comment: thanks. that helped. Need another favor, can you please help me with adding AutoPrefixer in my task. I tried multiple times but failed.

Comment: Actually I only use autoprefixer for the final code to be deployed - not together with sass - so I can't help you there.  But see an edit to the answer about another point.